# Undefined symbol: _GADUnifiedNativeIconAsset for GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am getting the below error after migrating to version 9.5.0.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GADUnifiedNativeIconAsset", referenced from:
-[GADFBNativeBannerAd didRenderInView:clickableAssetViews:nonclickableAssetViews:viewController:] in FacebookAdapter(GADFBNativeBannerAd.o)
-[GADFBUnifiedNativeAd didRenderInView:clickableAssetViews:nonclickableAssetViews:viewController:] in FacebookAdapter(GADFBUnifiedNativeAd.o)
-[GADFBNativeRenderer didRenderInView:clickableAssetViews:nonclickableAssetViews:viewController:] in FacebookAdapter(GADFBNativeRenderer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
Showing All Errors Only
Undefined symbol: _GADUnifiedNativeIconAsset
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Facebook sdks resolved this issue for me-
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '9.0.0'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '6.10.0'

GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook and FBAudienceNetwork versions may differ based on Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK version

Comment: I am trying tp add the Applovin with Google mediation adapter. But I am using the GoogleAds as  a old version. If so shall i need to updated the Google MobileAds, FBAudience and the mediation network?

Comment: is there any latest solution?